# How to count the number of times the screen has been touched? SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, touch, wkwebview

How to get the number of times the screen has been touched in Swift?

iOS wkwebview application.

This code doesn't work:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    counter++
    print(counter)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that wkwebview handles the touches of it's inside view, you can't "reach" it outside of it. Your best shot might be to inject some javascript code which can send a message if the user touches the document

You can read about javascript messages and the wkwebviews [here](https://medium.com/john-lewis-software-engineering/ios-wkwebview-communication-using-javascript-and-swift-ee077e0127eb)